# Div0 with case when in sql

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to transform this row code sql :

```
div0(COL1,COL2) * 100 AS NEW_COL,
```

by integrating a case when with a condition on date:

```
div0(CASE WHEN COL1='2022-03-11' THEN (COL1,COL2) ELSE 0 END) AS NEW_COL
```

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to be used as conditional aggregation then:

```
SELECT SUM(IFF(COLX='2022-03-11', DIV0(COL1, COL2), 0)) 
FROM tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

So the logic off IFF's or CASE's and DIV0's seems to "just work fine"

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,sum(column2) as COL1
    ,sum(column3) as COL2
    ,div0(COL1,COL2) * 100 AS NEW_COL
    ,IFF(col1='41',div0(COL1,COL2), 0) AS NEW_COL_IFF
    ,CASE WHEN col1='41' THEN div0(COL1,COL2) ELSE 0 END AS NEW_COL_CASE
FROM VALUES 
    (1, 10, 100),  
    (1, 11, 101),
    (2, 20, null),  
    (2, 21, null),
    (3, 30, 0),  
    (3, 31, 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

but the comment:

> I've an error like : Aggregate functions cannot be nested

is saying you are doing something like:

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,sum(column2) as COL1
    ,sum(column3) as COL2
    ,div0(COL1,COL2) * 100 AS NEW_COL
    ,IFF(col1='41',div0(COL1,COL2), 0) AS NEW_COL_IFF
    ,count(new_col_iff) as c_new_col_iff
FROM VALUES 
    (1, 10, 100),  
    (1, 11, 101),
    (2, 20, null),  
    (2, 21, null),
    (3, 30, 0),  
    (3, 31, 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

which creates:

> Aggregate functions cannot be nested: [SUM(VALUES.COLUMN2)] nested in [COUNT(NEW_COL_IFF)]

because the GROUP BY is used for the SUM's but, what window logic should be used to answer the COUNT. Snowflake is saying "you are doing to much at once"

which ether means simplify, but moving the "extra layer of aggregation to a new select layer, to make the order of operations clear to the compiler:

```
SELECT a.*
    ,count(new_col_iff) as c_new_col_iff
FROM (
    SELECT 
        column1
        ,sum(column2) as COL1
        ,sum(column3) as COL2
        ,div0(COL1,COL2) * 100 AS NEW_COL
        ,IFF(col1='41',div0(COL1,COL2), 0) AS NEW_COL_IFF
    FROM VALUES 
        (1, 10, 100),  
        (1, 11, 101),
        (2, 20, null),  
        (2, 21, null),
        (3, 30, 0),  
        (3, 31, 0)
    GROUP BY 1
) AS a
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY 1;
```

| COLUMN1 | COL1 | COL2 | NEW_COL | NEW_COL_IFF | C_NEW_COL_IFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 201 | 10.4477 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 41 | null | null | null | 0 |
| 3 | 61 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

OR be more explicit:

```
SELECT 
    column1
    ,sum(column2) as COL1
    ,sum(column3) as COL2
    ,div0(COL1,COL2) * 100 AS NEW_COL
    ,IFF(col1='41',div0(COL1,COL2), 0) AS NEW_COL_IFF
    ,count(new_col_iff) over () as c_new_col_iff
FROM VALUES 
    (1, 10, 100),  
    (1, 11, 101),
    (2, 20, null),  
    (2, 21, null),
    (3, 30, 0),  
    (3, 31, 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

which has different SUM result:

| COLUMN1 | COL1 | COL2 | NEW_COL | NEW_COL_IFF | C_NEW_COL_IFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 201 | 10.4477 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 41 | null | null | null | 2 |
| 3 | 61 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

but that can be made to be the same:

```
,count(new_col_iff) over (partition by column1) as c_new_col_iff
```

| COLUMN1 | COL1 | COL2 | NEW_COL | NEW_COL_IFF | C_NEW_COL_IFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 201 | 10.4477 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 41 | null | null | null | 0 |
| 3 | 61 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

So the point of all this, separate out the math you are doing, and then sort out the minimum steps needed to communicate this to the SQL engine, AND more importantly, the next person reading you SQL.